# How to handle DocuSign Authentication Assertion in an embedded signature request

Tags: docusignapi

I don't see in the API walk-through where to make the authentication assertion. I'm including it after the return URL but am not sure this is correct.

```
$data = array(
  "returnUrl" => "http://foo.com/docusign_step_2/",
  "authenticationMethod" => "None",
  "email" => $email,
  "userName" => $name,
  "clientUserId" => $clientUserId,
);

//Authentication Assertion
$RequestRecipientTokenParams = new RequestRecipientToken();
$RequestRecipientTokenParams->EnvelopeID = $envelopeId;
$RequestRecipientTokenParams->AuthenticationAssertion->AuthenticationInstant = date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".date("d")."T00:00:00.00";
$RequestRecipientTokenParams->AuthenticationAssertion->AuthenticationMethod = "Password";
$RequestRecipientTokenParams->AuthenticationAssertion->SecurityDomain = "YourApp.com";
```

...
Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DocuSign SOAP API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSignAPI_Guide.pdf) contains information about the schema of the RequestRecipientToken request.  Specifically, see page 94-97.

Note: "returnUrl" is not used in the RequestRecipientToken operation -- instead, you specify ClientURLs (as described in pages 94-97 of the SOAP API guide).

Comment: Currently, I am using the REST embedded sighing view where we generate a client user id and get an embedded URL that the client accesses to move through the signing process. What I am trying to determine, is what do the recipient tokens give me that I don't already get with my current implementation?

Comment: So, you already have a working implementation of embedded signing using the REST API (i.e., creating the envelope with an embedded recipient and then using "POST Recipient View" operation to get the URL that launches the recipient's signing session)?  That REST API method (POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient) gives you the same exact thing as the SOAP operation "RequestRecipientToken" -- i.e., both return the URL that can be used to launch the "embedded/captive" recipient's signing session. Regarding functionality, no inherent advantage to using one or the other.

Comment: Cool. So, what i noticed is that in the in my REST implementation, i don't see anything equivalent to the authentication assertion I mentioned above, i.e., passing a authentication id, authentication instant, security domain, etc. In my REST implementation, i am using a ClientUserId to identify the user, which is (it seems to me) is a weaker way of "guaranteeing" the user. Is there documentation to do the same thing using the REST api?

Comment: There's no equivalent of "authentication assertion" in the REST API. Truth be told, **AuthenticationAssertion** information that an integrated application supplies when making the RequestRecipientToken call with the SOAP API doesn't do anything to "guarantee" the user -- DocuSign doesn't validate or verify this information in any way.  i.e., you could supply totally bogus data for AuthenticationAssertion and the RequestRecipientToken call would work just fine -- therefore, no real advantage to using the SOAP call over the REST call.